# Compute The Next Cluster

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader, osdev, fat

Recently I read some nice tutorials about OS development on [BrokenThorn](http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev6.html) : it's a nice OSDev series.

I have some trouble to understand the idea of "computing the next cluster" when I want to  load the stage 2 of our bootloader. The code is :

```
      mov     ax, WORD [cluster]  ; The current Cluster.
      mov     cx, ax              ; copy current cluster
      mov     dx, ax              ; copy current cluster
      shr     dx, 0x0001          ; divide by two
      add     cx, dx              ; sum for (3/2)

      mov     bx, 0x0200          ; location of FAT in memory
      add     bx, cx              ; index into FAT
      mov     dx, WORD [bx]       ; read two bytes from FAT

      test    ax, 0x0001

      jnz     .ODD_CLUSTER
      jz      .EVEN_CLUSTER
```

Why we multiply the current cluster number by 3/2 to get the next cluster number?

Answer (score 3):

I found The same Question in the assembly Tag, But I can't find it to reference it !! (it's very helpful) Sorry.

So, Why we Multiply the index by 3/2 To Get the index of the Next cluster ??

First of all we need clarify some ideas :

***What is an Enrty in the FAT table ??***

**Is a peace of memory of 12-bits in long.So, FAT table is an ensemble of this Entries.**

***What there is in this Entries ??***

**In this peace of Memory there is an index (Number), this index refer to an entry in the same FAT table (how many Entry from the FAT Start address).**

Each Entry is 12 bits long :

```
<---- 12 bits ----><---- 12 bits ----><---- 12 bits ----><---- 12 bits ---->
    1st index          2nd index          3rd index         4th index
```

When we get The first Index from the Root Directory (for Example: 4), So we should Go to This index in The FAT table to find the index for the next cluster number. How we will proceed ??

We need the start address of FAT table (easy to find), And will Just add the index.Like this:

```
     mov bx, [FAT address]   ; Strat address of FAT table
     mov ax, [cluster]       ;the index (for ex: 4)
     add bx, ax              ;Start address + index = the next Entry (cluster).
```

Easy :-)!!

**But where is the 3/2 fraction ?? :-D .** 
the above code is Wrong, why ?? 
The logic is Correct ,but there is a misunderstand of "**The addressing unit**".
in most CPUs The Unit addressing is **BYTE(8-bits)**, so When we Make **[index]** that's mean: **index * 8-bits** in the Memory.
so when we made [cluster] ---> index * 8-bits,Like this we will indexing Entries of 8-bits long.

As against this, Our index is 12-bits not 8-bits !!! So how solve this Big problem lool??

**The Solution:**
We should just Multiply the [cluster] by 3/2, So : 
**index * 8bits * 3/2 = index* 12bits**. that's what we need !! Now we can indexing the memory By 12-bits unit (1.5 byte).
The correct code is :

```
     mov bx, [FAT address]   ; Strat address of FAT table
     mov ax, [cluster]       ;the index (for ex: 4)
     mov dx, ax              ; make copy of index
     shr dx, 0x0001          ; divide it By 2.
     add ax, dx              ; index/2 + index = index * 3/2.
     add bx, ax              ;Start address + index = the next Entry (cluster).
```

I'm newbie , so if there is something wrong just Notify it ;-D !! Thankx.

Answer (score 1):

This weirdness is specific for FAT12 file systems.

Since size of a record for cluster in FAT12 is 12 bits, in order to compute its offset (in bytes) in the file allocation table you need to take its index and multiply it by 3/2 (or 12bits/8bits).

A cluster record contains number of the next cluster (like pointer in a linked list) of file or end-of-file marks. For free clusters a cluster record may mark bad clusters or just is free.

Comment: Thanks EarlGray For Your response. I search hard & i get it out. think i should make a tutorial for this . lool

Answer (score 1):

Remember this is FAT12: each cluster is 12 bits. Because a byte is 8 bits, one entry is one byte and half, or 3/2 bytes!